# Union select statements horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

let's say result of my select statements as follows (I have 5 of those):

```
   Id  Animal AnimalId
    1   Dog     Dog1
    1   Cat     Cat57

   Id  Transport TransportId
    2   Car        Car100
    2   Plane      Plane500
```

I'd like to get a result as follows:

```
   Id  Animal AnimalId    Transport    TransportId
    1   Dog     Dog1
    1   Cat     Cat57
    2                        Car          Car100
    2                       Plane         Plane500
```

What I can do is I can crate a tablevariable and specify all possible columns and insert records from each select statement into it. But maybe better solution like PIVOT?
      **Edit**

queries: 1st: `Select CategoryId as Id, Animal, AnimalId from Animal`
2nd: `Select CategoryId as Id, Transport, TransportId from Transport`

Comment: are these two related at all?

Comment: @bbluefeet, No they have one column with the same name: ID. each select statement has the same id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this, if you need them in the same rows, this gets the `row_number()` for each row and joins on those:

```
select a.id,
  a.aname,
  a.aid,
  t.tname,
  t.tid
from 
(
  select id, aname, aid, row_number() over(order by aid) rn
  from animal
) a
left join
(
  select id, tname, tid, row_number() over(order by tid) rn
  from transport
) t
  on a.rn = t.rn
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f69c1/2)

If you don't need them in the same row, then use `UNION ALL`:

```
select id, aname, aid, 'Animal' tbl
from animal
union all
select id, tname, tid, 'Transport'
from transport
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f69c1/4)

Edit #1, here is a version with an `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`:

```
select an_id, [aname], [aid], [tname], [tid]
from
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by col order by col) rn
  from animal
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (aname, aid)
  ) u
  union all
  select *, row_number() over(partition by col order by col) rn
  from transport
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (tname, tid)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  min(value)
  for col in([aname], [aid], [tname], [tid])
) p
order by an_id
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72a8f/31)

Comment: I think this is the best way to go, but given the output he wants it isn't quite right.

Comment: Thanks for the examples but both of them are having results different from what I showed. I need three datasets to be stacked and only column ID is common.

Comment: I need ids from both tables and columns from both tables *

Comment: @bluefeet, that looks cool. Let me test performance here. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This would do it for you:

```
SELECT
ID, field1, field2, '' as field3, '' as field4
FROM sometable

UNION ALL

SELECT
ID, '', '', field3, field4
FROM someothertable
```

Comment: Yeah, it would, just looking for a better solution if possible. Thanks though

Comment: What is it you don't you like about this solution? It is certainly how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to pivot, your results are already fine.

If you want, you can just UNION all 5 statements together in the same format as the first select: ID/Category/CategoryID.  Then you'll get one long result set with all 5 sets appended 3 columns wide.

Is that what you want?  Or do you need to distinguish between 'categories'?

---

given your example, try:

```
Select CategoryId as Id, Animal, AnimalId from Animal
union all
Select CategoryId as Id, Transport, TransportId from Transport
```

if you want, you can alias the columns like:

```
Select CategoryId as Id, Animal as category, AnimalId as categoryID from Animal
union all
Select CategoryId as Id, Transport, TransportId from Transport
```

---

you really don't need to pivot, just space out your columns like you were thinking initially.  You don't pivot to move columns, you pivot to perform an aggregate function over grouped data.

Comment: No I want them to reside in different columns

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Animal (
    Animal varchar(50)
    ,AnimalID varchar(50)
    )

create table Transport (
    Transport varchar(50)
    ,TransportID varchar(50)
    )

insert into Animal values ('Dog', 'Dog1')
insert into Animal values ('Cat', 'Cat57')

insert into Transport values ('Car', 'Car100')
insert into Transport values ('Plane', 'Plane500')


select  ID = 1
    ,A.Animal
    ,A.AnimalID
    ,Transport = ''
    ,TransportID = ''
from    Animal A

union

select  ID = 2
    ,Animal = ''
    ,AnimalID = ''
    ,T.Transport
    ,T.TransportID
from    Transport T
```

Comment: No idea what the purpose is but this will produce the exact result you want. Now, this is not a universal solution. It needs to be tailored to the exact result desired.

Comment: Yeah, it would thanks for suggestion, but still looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I am not sure there is any cleaner.

Comment: union vs union all is a topic of its own. Depends on what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

To get it in the format you want, select the values you want, and then `null` (or an empty string) for the other columns.

```
SELECT
    CategoryId as Id, 
    Animal as 'Animal', 
    AnimalId as 'AnimalId',
    null as 'Transport',
    null as 'TransportId'
FROM Animal
UNION
SELECT 
    CategoryId as Id, 
    null as 'Animal',
    null as 'AnimalId',
    Transport as 'Transport',  
    TransportId as 'TransportId' 
FROM Transport
```

I'm still not sure of the purpose of this, but this should give the output you want.