# Concatenate 2 SELECTS

Tags: postgresql

I have these 2 selects (select 1, 'a') and (select 2, 'b', 'x') and I want an output like 1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'x' can I do this in postgres without altering the selects?

I tried this:

```
select (select 1, 'a'), (select 2, 'b', 'x')
```

but the error is "subquery must return only one column".

Comment: Why you can't do just `select 1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'x'`. Plz describe your real use-case

Comment: If its just a single select (I mean only single rows from both select)what you have mentioned.
      
         `select A.*,B.* from (select 1, 'a' ) A,(select 2, 'b', 'x') B;`

Comment: I use a framework that has the queries already defined, is hard for me to rewrite them and I was hoping I can find a shortcut to reuse them.

Comment: So what exactly is the result you are looking for?

Comment: Always a single row of data

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the CONCAT function.

This link should help you: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-concat-function/

You'll probably be looking at some form of SELECT CONCAT(SELECT 1, SELECT 2, ...), but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
select * 
from (select 1, 'a') as a
left join (select 2, 'b', 'x') as b on (1=1)
```

is inspired from here
**[Union select statements horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395761/union-select-statements-horizontally)**

Also Syed Mushtaq comment works and seems easier to write.